# Docker build from Dockerfile hangs indefinitely and occasionally crashes with error 'failed to start service utility VM'

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

I am currently using Docker Desktop for Windows and following this tutorial for using Docker and VSCode ( https://scotch.io/tutorials/docker-and-visual-studio-code ) and when I am attempting to build the image, the daemon is able to complete the first step of the Dockerfile, but then hangs indefinitely on the second step. Sometimes, but very rarely, after an indeterminate amount of time, it will error out and give me this error

```
failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): CreateComputeSystem 97cb9905dbf6933f563d0337f8321c8cb71e543a242cddb0cb09dbbdbb68b006_svm: The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"container","Name":"97cb9905dbf6933f563d0337f8321c8cb71e543a242cddb0cb09dbbdbb68b006_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\Program Files\\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"kernel"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true})
```

I have made sure that virtualization is enabled on my machine, uninstalled and reinstalled Docker, uninstalled Docker and deleted all files related to it before reinstalling, as well as making sure that the experimental features are enabled. These are fixes that I have found from various forums while trying to find others who have had the same issue.

Here is the Dockerfile that I am trying to build from. I have double checked with the tutorial that it is correct, though its still possible that I missed something (outside of the version number in the FROM line).

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

I would expect the image to build correctly as I have followed the tutorial to a T. I have even full reset and started the tutorial over again and I'm still getting this same issue where it hangs indefinitely.

Comment: you using Docker ToolBox ?

Comment: No, I am using Docker Desktop for windows. Sorry, I should have specified that in my post. I'll edit that now

Answer (score 0):

well, you copy some files two times. I would not do that.
so for the minimum change to your `Dockerfile` I would try:

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

I would also think about the `&& mv node_modules ../` part, if it is really needed.
If you don't do it already I advise you to write a `.dockerignore` file right next to your `Dockerfile` with the minimum content of:

```
/node_modules
```

so that your local `node_modules` directory does not get also copied while building the image (saves time).

hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, after trying those changes, I wasn't able to get a different result.

Comment: @IHavePower, try restarting docker

Comment: It doesn't look like that helped either